# Unhandled IIS Exception - How can I track it down

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, event-log

I am seeing the following error in the event log.  It is coming from our ASP.Net application.  I am having trouble tracking down what is causing the error.  Any suggestions appreciated!

- **OS**: Windows Server 2000
- **WebServer**: IIS 6
- **Application**: ASP.Net v3.5

**Error Log**

> [MachineName] has logged the following
>   Error for IIS
>
> Details: ComputerName=[ComputerName]
>   User=Not specified Logfile=Application
>   Type=Error EventType=1
>   SourceName=ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
>   Category=0 CategoryString=Not
>   specified EventCode=1334
>   EventID=-1073740490
>   TimeGenerated=20091125101806.000000-360
>   TimeWritten=20091125101806.000000-360
>   Message=An unhandled exception
>   occurred and the process was
>   terminated.
>
> Application ID: DefaultDomain Process
>   ID: 1440 Exception:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>   Message: Unable to find assembly
>   'Company.Common, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
>   assemblyInfo, String name)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
>   objectName, String[] memberNames,
>   BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
>   Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[]
>   memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
>   objectReader, Int32 objectId,
>   BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
>   SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
>   record)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser,
>   Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler
>   handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream
>   stm)    at
>   System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[]
>   blob)    at
>   System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[]
>   blob)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a custom unhanded exception module, which allowed retrieval of more information about the origin of the bug, and the eventual resolution of the issue.

Here is a link to a codeplex project that has code for an unhanded exception module:
http://unhandledexception.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80132

Comment: Looks like the codeplex url's changed. Working link: http://unhandledexception.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest

Answer (score 1):

Try the IIS Debug Diagnostics tools

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the text "Unable to find assembly 'Company.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'".

Are you missing an assembly, or do you have a version problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error says the assembly can't be found. If it's in the bin folder and correctly formatted, then perhaps it's a permission error?

Does your Company.Common assembly have permissions that allow it to be read by your IIS AppPool identity?

You might also double-check to make sure that the assembly is listed in the system.web / compilation / assemblies section of your web.config.

Comment: No unusual permissions are set, they all look standard and work for all other code.  It is not in the system.web / compilation / assemblies, but it is not strongly signed or in the GAC and it all compiles fine.

Comment: Are you doing server-side compilation (as a "web site" project), or client-side compilation ("web application" project)?